# Expressing polynomial roots expression in terms of coefficients

Tags: polynomials, roots

This is my first question on MSE. Apologies in advance for any textual or LaTeX errors.

I'm stuck with this problem:

> Given  $x^3 - bx^2 + cx - d = 0$ has roots $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, find an expression in terms of $b$, $c$ and $d$ for:
>
> (i) $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2$
>
> (ii) $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3$
>
> (iii) $(1 + \alpha^3)(1 + \beta^3)(1 + \gamma^3)$

I had no trouble with (i) or (ii), but got stuck on (iii) as follows: Expanding,
$$\begin{align*}
(1 + \alpha^3)(1 + \beta^3)(1 + \gamma^3) & = (1 + \alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \alpha^3\beta^3)(1 + \gamma^3)\\ 
& = 1 + (\alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3) + (\alpha^3\beta^3 + \beta^3\gamma^3 + \gamma^3\alpha^3) + \alpha^3\beta^3\gamma^3
\end{align*}$$

The first, second and fourth RHS terms are no problem, leaving us with:
$$\alpha^3\beta^3 + \beta^3\gamma^3 + \gamma^3\alpha^3 = \left(\frac{1}{\gamma^3} + \frac{1}{\alpha^3} + \frac{1}{\beta^3} \right)\alpha^3\beta^3\gamma^3$$

So now we are left with the term in brackets. My next thought was to transform the original polynomial to one with roots $\frac{1}{\alpha}$, $\frac{1}{\beta}$ and $\frac{1}{\gamma}$ and then use the answer to (ii) above. Will this work? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Math goes in MathJax - the entire question body doesn't. I appreciate your apology, and I sincerely implore you to [take a look here at how I've edited your question](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/f4d2e5f8-3bb9-4b01-91b6-a7922e808d0e/view-source) and try to emulate it in the future. [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: The polynomial with roots $1/\alpha,1/\beta,1/\gamma$ is $dx^3-cx^2+bx-1$.

Comment: @Gerry Thanks for the hint. I tried this, but got to the same point as in my OP in a long and gruesome series of algebraic manipulations! I'm now checking a simple example to see if Lab's method works in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=1+\alpha^3$

Again, $\alpha^3=b\alpha^2-c\alpha+d$

$$\implies y-1-d=b\alpha^2-c\alpha$$

Cubing  we get  $$ (y-1-d)^3=b^3\alpha^6-c^3\alpha^3-3bc\alpha^2\cdot \alpha(b\alpha^2-c\alpha)$$
$$(y-1-d)^3=b^3(y-1)^2-c^3(y-1)-3bc(y-1)(y-1-d)$$ as $\alpha^3=y-1,b\alpha^2-c\alpha=y-1-d$

Arrange as $y^3+By^2+Cy+D=0$ whose roots are $1 + \alpha^3,1 + \beta^3,1 + \gamma^3$

Using [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas),
$$(1 + \alpha^3)(1 + \beta^3)(1 + \gamma^3)=-D$$

Comment: @Zev Many thanks, will read these references

Comment: @GuyCorrigall, observe that this method can be applied to other two cases as well

Comment: Thank you. Your answer prompts me to transform the original polynomial into one with roots 1+α3 etc.I'll give this a go.

Comment: I made it! A very long and error prone series of algebraic manipulations, but confirmed correct by trialling a cubic with roots 1, 2 and 3 and substituting in your 'arranged' cubic whose coefficients depend only on b,c and d. One question, though; I can't quite see why simply cubing the expression for y in terms of alpha leads to the correct cubic with the correct roots (1+alpha, etc). Can you elucidate?

Comment: @GuyCorrigall, if you meant to cube $y=b\alpha^2-c\alpha+(1+d),$ it will tough to remove $\alpha$ from the expression. Also observe that here we only need the coefficient of $y^3$ which is $1$ here, the constant term $(D)$ which is $-(1+d)^3-b^3+c^3+3bc(1+d)$

Comment: @GuyCorrigall,  you  may try putting $y=\alpha^2$ or $y=\alpha^3$ to find the rest two solutions following the same approach

Comment: @GuyCorrigall, nice to hear that